# In MATLAB, how can I count the unique number of index values associated with a condition?

Tags: matlab, count, indexing, unique

I have a 2-D matrix containing, in the first column, the index of the experimental condition, and in the second column, the index of the corresponding experiment, i.e. `[condition experiment]`. Each row corresponds to one interesting event (one experiment can produce one or several events).

Counting conditions and events is easy. I'd like to know how to count how many unique experiments there were for each given condition.

This is the solution I have right now using [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html), but I think there should be a simpler or more elegant solution:

```
idxList = [1 1;...  %# There are two experiments for condition 1...
           1 2;...
           1 2;...
           2 1;...  %# ...and 1 experiment for condition 2.
           2 1];
accumarray(idxList(:,1),idxList(:,2),[],@(x)length(unique(x)))
ans =
     2
     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives:

- Use the entire matrix `idxList` for the `subs` argument to [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) (i.e. specify both row and column indices for the accumulation), then sum the number of non-zeroes across the rows of the result:

  ```
  experCounts = sum(accumarray(idxList,1) > 0,2);
  ```
- Use [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) on `idxList` first to remove duplicate rows, which simplifies the call to [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

  ```
  idxList = unique(idxList,'rows');
  experCounts = accumarray(idxList(:,1),1);
  ```

Comment: The first solution is very nice. Thanks!